# How to fix this UnicodeDecodeError in Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, scons, nuitka

I'm running nuitka and getting an UnicodeDecodeError.

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --plugin-enable=tk-inter MyProgram.py
```

*UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 74: invalid continuation byte
scons: [MyProgram.build\module.babel.core.obj] UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 79: invalid continuation byte*

**MyProgram.py**

```
import datetime
import glob
import mysql.connector
import openpyxl
import os
import PyPDF4
import sys
import tkcalendar
import tkinter.filedialog, tkinter.messagebox, tkinter.ttk

version = 0.03

def verify():
    comp = datetime.datetime.strptime(base.get(), "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-01")
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Planilha Excel", "Selecione a planilha")
    xlsx = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "M:\\", title = "Selecione a planilha", filetypes = [("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
    pbar["value"] = 5
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Pasta", "Selecione a pasta contendo os arquivos pdf")
    directory = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "M:\\", title = "Selecione a pasta contendo os arquivos pdf")
    pbar["value"] = 10
    wbterc = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx, read_only = True)
    sheeterc = wbterc.active
    pbar["value"] = 20
    listerc = []
    i = 3
    cell = sheeterc.cell(row = 1, column = 1)
    while cell.value != None:
        cell = sheeterc.cell(row = 1, column = 1)
        ctr = cell.value
        cell = sheeterc.cell(row = i, column = 5)
        dep = cell.value
        cell = sheeterc.cell(row = i, column = 6)
        sb = cell.value
        cell = sheeterc.cell(row = i, column = 2)
        cpf = str(cell.value).replace("-", "").replace(".", "")
        cell = sheeterc.cell(row = i, column = 1)
        nameterc = cell.value
        listerc.append((ctr, comp, dep, sb, cpf, nameterc))
        pbar["value"] = i + 20
        i = i + 1
    col1 = "CTR"
    col2 = "COMPETENCIA"
    col3 = "AG_LOTACAO"
    col4 = "SB_LOTACAO"
    col5 = "CPF_TERC"
    col6 = "NOME_TERC"
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.title = "TERCEIRIZADOS"
    worksheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = directory
    worksheet.cell(row = 2, column = 1).value = col1
    worksheet.cell(row = 2, column = 2).value = col2
    worksheet.cell(row = 2, column = 3).value = col3
    worksheet.cell(row = 2, column = 4).value = col4
    worksheet.cell(row = 2, column = 5).value = col5
    worksheet.cell(row = 2, column = 6).value = col6
    indexfile = 7
    indexname = 3
    os.chdir(directory)
    for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
        pdf = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(directory + "/" + file)
        worksheet.cell(row = 2, column = indexfile).value = file
        numpages = pdf.getNumPages()
        data = ""
        i = 0
        while i < numpages:
            pdfReader = pdf.getPage(i).extractText()
            data = data + pdfReader
            i = i + 1
        for tupterc in listerc:
            nameterc = tupterc[5]
            if nameterc == None:
                break
            worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = 1).value = tupterc[0]
            worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = 2).value = tupterc[1]
            worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = 3).value = tupterc[2]
            worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = 4).value = tupterc[3]
            worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = 5).value = int(tupterc[4])
            worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = 6).value = tupterc[5]
            stmt = "replace into terceirizados.TERCEIRIZADOS (" + col1 + ", " + col2 + ", " + col3 + ", " + col4 + ", " + col5 + ", " + col6 + ") values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cur.execute(stmt, tupterc)
            if nameterc in data:
                worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = indexfile).value = "SIM"
            else:
                worksheet.cell(row = indexname, column = indexfile).value = "NÃO"
            pbar["value"] = indexname + 100
            indexname = indexname + 1
            dbconn.commit()
    dbconn.close()
    pbar["value"] = 100
    destfilename = directory + "/testeverificacaoterceirizados_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y") + ".xlsx"
    workbook.save(filename = destfilename)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Fim", "Relatório resultante salvo em " + directory)
    os.startfile(destfilename)
    pbar["value"] = 100

dbconn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "pxl0hosp0164.dispositivos.bb.com.br", user = "terceirizados", password = "7417pd2", port = 3306
)
cur = dbconn.cursor()
cur.execute("Select max(V.VERSAO) from terceirizados.VERSIONAMENTO V")
v = cur.fetchone()

if float(v[0]) == version:
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("MyProgram - v" + str(version))
    window.geometry("350x200")
    label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Defina a competência: ")
    label.place(relx = 0.185, rely = 0.3, anchor = "center")
    comp = datetime.datetime.now()
    base = tkcalendar.DateEntry(window)
    base.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.3, anchor = "center")
    button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "VERIFICAR", command = verify)
    button.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
    pbar = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(window, length = 100)
    pbar.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.7, anchor = "center")
    pbar["value"] = 0
    window.mainloop()
else:
    dbconn.close()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Atualização", "Programa desatualizado")
```

How to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

You have accent characters in your source file:

- Relatório resultante salvo
- Defina a competência
- Atualização

Ensure that your whole toolchain (nuitka/scons/...) expects input files in UTF-8 format, and also ensure that the source file `MyProgram.py` is stored in UTF-8 encoding, too.

The latter seems to not be the case, so the decoding chokes on characters that are stored in some local ASCII encoding (Brazilian portuguese? Code page 860?).

Comment: It may be that the error isn't exactly in those places that I listed above. Try to narrow the search space by removing half of your program (roughly), then trying again. If the compile works then, you know the error is in the removed half. If not, then halve the program a second time...and so on (bisection!).